# Scrapy ImagesPipeline not activated for Amazon S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, scrapy, pipeline

I want to store images directly to amazon s3.
Here's my settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'car_scraper.pipelines.MongoPipeline': 10,
    'car_scraper.pipelines.SubscriptionsPipeline': 20,
    'car_scraper.pipelines.PhotosPipeline': 1,
}

IMAGES_STORE = 's3://dev-images/photos'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '...'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '...'
```

But when I run crawl, I see in the logs:

```
INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['car_scraper.pipelines.MongoPipeline',
 'car_scraper.pipelines.SubscriptionsPipeline']
```

And if I change IMAGES_STORE

```
IMAGES_STORE = '/Users/user/Documents/img_car'
```

in the logs:

```
INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['car_scraper.pipelines.PhotosPipeline',
 'car_scraper.pipelines.MongoPipeline',
 'car_scraper.pipelines.SubscriptionsPipeline']
```

and photos saved.
Why doesn't start PhotosPipeline for S3?

PhotosPipeline:

```
Class PhotosPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['photos']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        photos = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not photos:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no photos")
        item['photos'] = photos
        return item
```

Comment: `pip install botocore` should do it

Comment: I installed, it didn't help

Comment: replace your photo pipeline with this `scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline`, if this doesn't work you're not passing correct image urls

Comment: With IMAGES_STORE = '/Users/user/Documents/img_car' photos saved in the folder.